# missed calls not appearing as notifications

Tags: notifications, htc-sense, htc-one-x, missed-calls

I have a HTC one x with the default HTC sense. Missed calls do not appear in the notification list which is frustrating ... The calls appear in the call history log so it knows about them. I've also tried calling myself with a another phone and it all appears as normal but when the call is hung up, no notification appears.

I'm sure it use to show notifications and I cannot find any settings that would control this.

Will factory reset if this just seems wrong/buggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to factory reset.

Just go to `Settings` → `Call`. Scroll down to the bottom and enable `Show caller ID for missed calls on lock screen and status bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Under settings go to Application Manager. Search for "BadgeProvider".
Tap "clear data"
Tap "ok".

Your green phone icon should now show number of calls missed. This does not delete any personal data.